# Quicker way to insert non-matching ids to column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a quicker way to get the ids that exist in `table1` but not exist in `table2` and insert them in `table2`?

```
insert into table2 (id) 
select id 
from table1 
where table1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

Comment: Check the execution plan. You might want to try `not exists` with a co-related sub-query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is the difference between `not exists` and `not in` ?

Comment: try both, review the execution plan of both, and you'll begin to understand some of the differences (if there are any in the RDBMS you're using)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, the equivalent query would be 
`insert into table2 (id) 
select id 
from table1 
where table1.id not exists (select id from table2)`????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your solution using the `in` operator try the `exists` one

```
select id
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table2
    where id = t1.id 
)
```

If the subquery returns an empty set `not exists` evaluates to `true`

The `outer join`

```
select id
from
    table1 t1
    left join
    table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Use `explain analyze` to compare